# Apple Mail app search filter brings the same email hundred times

Tags: mail.app

Not sure where to address this issue, though, this Apple Mail (bug?) is incredibly annoying.

[image: example input]

Searching for something brings the same email 100 times, +thousands of bin entries. Why this behavior? How to fix that? It simply makes impossible finding any emails.

After the last update, it became even more annoying. Now it shows "Deleted Messages" as well.

[image]

Those aren't even actually deleted messages. They are trash of autosave process.

Comment: have you deleted the email from the bin folder?

Comment: There are thousand versions of the same email in the bin folder every time I compose any. This looks like some buggy auto-save behavior.

Comment: What type of email account is this that you have hooked Apple Mail up to? Who is the service provider (Google Gmail, AOL, Comcast, etc.)? Is it configured for POP or IMAP? Very likely it the problem results from a combination of configuration settings on both the email provider end and the Apple Mail end. If you will name the provider and the type of email account, it will help in troubleshooting.

Comment: It is Google (google.com/a), and it is configured over IMAP.

Comment: Not any help, but I've heard a few people complain about this continuous autosave bug, specifically with Google accounts. Not sure if it's Mail.app or Google's rather unique take on IMAP that's the problem, though...

Comment: Still having problems with it, just in case. Furthermore, searching for some text strings that are present in old mails does not always turn results. Instead, if I go to gmail.com/ and query for the same thing, I get all the emails as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create an email Mail.app saves a draft. When you type a few more letters Mail.app deletes the old draft and saves a new one.

If you have "store draft messages on the server" selected (Preferences -> Accounts -> (select account) -> Mailbox behaviours) then every time you make an edit Mail.app sends it to Google then deletes any old drafts. Unfortunately, Google doesn't really delete the old drafts. Instead it moves them to the Bin folder and when you search in Mail.app it finds these hundreds of old drafts.

To stop this occurring on future drafts uncheck "store draft messages on the server" for all my Gmail accounts.

To clear up your old drafts log into to Gmail directly and:
* Go to the All Mail folder and manually select and delete all the old drafts
* Go to the Bin folder and select "Empty Bin"

Comment: The answer that is checked was helpful but this turned out to be the answer to my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Empty the trash and try "Mailbox -> Rebuild".

Comment: Don't know whether that's permanent fix, but certainly makes things work better now.